# Android Volley + Java : set object's field from callback interface

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have maybe very silly question.

I'm using Volley library for network communication :

```
getGeocodingResults(finalDepartureUrl, new IVolleyCallback() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                       handleVolleyResponse(jsonObject, order, 1);
                  }
            });

// getGeocodingResults method : 

  private void getGeocodingResults(String url, final IVolleyCallback iVolleyCallback)
    {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url.toString(), null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        iVolleyCallback.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                // hide the progress dialog
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);

    }
```

handleVolleyResponse method is a point - I want to set the Order's field value :

```
private void handleVolleyResponse(JSONObject jsonObject, Order order, int flag) {
       /*
        * here is JSONObject data parsing
        * and now I want set parsed value latlng to Order's object field
        */

        synchronized (order) {
            switch (flag) {
                case 1:
                    OrdersFragment.getOrdersList().get(OrdersFragment.getOrdersList().indexOf(order)).setDeparturePoint(latLng);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    OrdersFragment.getOrdersList().get(OrdersFragment.getOrdersList().indexOf(order)).setDestinationPoint(latLng);
    /* I tried also like this      order.setDestinationPoint(latLng);*/

                    break;
            }

        }

    }
```

But when I check order's values when the `handleVolleyResponse` finish working, the new values isn't setting to Order's object.

OrdersFragment.getOrdersList() is `volatile`

How can I set the field to the object ?